# Share and modify a variable across multiple modules/classes in python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

What I am trying to do is to setup a scraper to different wiki images sites, and get the links in "realtime" from different classes/modules.

The structure is basically:

main.py : Calls the threaded process to the scrapers
scraperwiki1.py, scraperwiki2.py are the ones getting the results

What I have now is that in the main.py it calls the scrapers and wait for a return:

```
scraped_images = scraperwiki1(url)... etc etc 
(this is actually threaded to call multiple scrapers at once, but I am simplifying here)
```

and on each scraperwiki:

```
imageList = []
r = requests.get(url).content
result =  ... scraper functions ...
for images in result:
 imageList.append(images)
return imageList
```

But besides waiting for the scraperwiki1, scraperwiki2 to process all the links and then return the result as a list, is there anything I can do to get those results while it is still going?

I tried to setup a global in the main.py

```
scraped_images = []
global scraped_images
```

and then in scraperwiki1 and scraperwiki2

```
import scraped_images
r = requests.get(url).content
result =  ... scraper functions ...
for images in result:
 scraped_images.append(images)
```

but it seems I am not able to access and append to the lists in this way.

Is there a way to optimize this process? Because sometimes scraping large pages will take a while.

Thanks in advance